# Command ID in Eclipse 4

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

What is the ID of a Command in Eclipse 4 used for? Can it be a random user-selected string, or must it specify some sort of ID/package/class/etc.?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id is used when you define Handlers, Key Bindings, Handled Menu and Toolbar Items for the command or when you want to reference the command from Java code.

The id should be a unique value in your application. The id is not related to Java packages but conventionally has a similar format.

There are a small number of command ids which are known to the core Eclipse code (such as the `org.eclipse.ui.file.exit` command you show) and need to use that exact value.

Comment: For each command, do I have to create a handler associated with the command ID? What happens if there are multiple handlers sharing the same command ID? What happens if there are no handler for a command? Why don't I need a handler for the `org.eclipse.ui.file.exit` command but it still works when I add that command to a menu item?

Comment: `org.eclipse.ui.file.exit` works because the core code has a handler for that. Yes you need handler(s) for a command. You can have multiple handlers as long as their scope doesn't overlap.